# Allowing only backspaces in a textarea with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have a textarea inside which you can only input characters using on-screen buttons, so the textarea editing by keyboard is disabled. But I would like to allow the user to delete what he has input, using the backspace stroke. Is there a way to do this in Javascript?

Comment: Do you want this to delete one character or a whole word?

Comment: `$(elem).val($(elem).val().slice(0,-1));` something like this?

Comment: Given you already have on-screen buttons, can't you create another button that does backspace?

Comment: Yes. Add a key event listener and only `preventDefault` if it isn't key 7 (From memory, I think 7 is backspace. Could be wrong. Simple test: log the key when it's pressed)

Comment: dang, it's 8. So close! Also 46 is delete.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's quite easy to selectively enable keys. Just add a key listener and `preventDefault` when it's a key you don't want:

```
myInputElement.addEventListener( 'keydown', function( e ) {
//  console.log( e.keyCode ); // for finding key codes by trying them
    if( e.keyCode >= 37 && e.keyCode <= 40 ) {
        return; // arrow keys
    }
    if( e.keyCode === 8 || e.keyCode === 46 ) {
        return; // backspace (8) / delete (46)
    }
    e.preventDefault( );
}, false );
```

(example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tnayV/)

Comment: you may also want to allow anything which has a modifier key set (cmd/ctrl/alt), to allow cut/copy/paste/select-all/etc. They're possible through the menus anyway so no real point restricting them.

Answer (score 1):

Another example allowing only backsapce:

```
document.getElementById('mytextarea').addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
    if (e.which != 8){
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
}, false);
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/RjbdH/2/)